# Limit origin of iframe served from file://

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, webkit, sandbox

I have an offline web app (HTML5) which runs from the local filesystem (file://) in a webkit-based browser.

This app allows for 3rd-party HTML5-widgets to be displayed. These are also stored locally (file://) and displayed within an Iframe.

Since both html-files are served from file://, they appear to be from the same origin, and thus share  LocalStorage and SessionStorage. This is a problem since  3rd-party widgets have access to each other's data.

I want to limit this functionality so that each widget has (kind of) their own isolated localStorage.

I tried setting the `sandbox`-attribute on the iframe. This disabled localStorage completely (throws SecurityError).

I tried setting `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"` but this creates the same behavior as before (all widgets have access to all data), since the origin is the same for all widgets (file://)

The next thing I tried was modifying  `Storage.prototype` to prefix all localStorage-keys with the url/path of the calling iframe-document (to create a fake origin-handling). This works fine in the first iframe using `<iframe>.contentWindow.Storage.prototype`, but breaks if the widget nests its own iframe. The nested iframe would get its own Storage-object with an untouched prototype and would access the raw localStorage data.

I thought about creating some kind of recursive thing that detects all nested iframes and runs my "sandboxing"-task on that iframe, but I could not find a good way to do so. Extending `HTMLIframeElement.prototype` did not work with iframes created by markup or document.createElement. I also made some experiments with `MutationObserver` on the iframe-document but that would probably be a performance killer (browser runs on an embedded system with limited resources).

Ideally, I would like the widgets to run in a sandboxed iframe with support for localStorage, but with its own origin (so it can't access other widgets' data or the parent page's data).

Any suggestion is appreciated! :)